# Tkinter label text isn't being updated

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```py
import tkinter

win = tkinter.Tk()

c=0

def click():
   global c

   c+=1

b=tkinter.Button(win, text='click', command=click).pack()

l=tkinter.Label(win, text=c).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that your `click` function just changes the value of the `c` variable. After this you should send the new `c` value to your `l` label. Also, try to avoid using objects initializing together with `pack`, `place` etc methods because you lose the reference to your objects. In this case `Label` type will not be passed to your variable and `l` will be NoneType.

```
import tkinter

win = tkinter.Tk()

c=0

def click():
   global c

   c+=1
   l.configure(text=c)

b=tkinter.Button(win, text='click', command=click).pack()

l=tkinter.Label(win, text=c)
l.pack()

win.mainloop()
```